# PyInstaller create an .exe file, but when -w is used .exe fails to run the script

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create .exe file of an .py script, it works fine when I use pyinstaller --onefile --icon favicon.ico AutoClicker.py But when I run pyinstaller --onefile -w --icon favicon.ico AutoClicker.py it does creates an .exe file, but when running the file Failed to run script is prompted.

imported in the files are: pyautogui, time, tkinter, webbrowser, keyboard, os, sys, datetime, threading

Cannot paste code here cause it is too long, a part of it is below, do not know how useful will it be

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    your_gui = YourGUI()
    your_gui.geometry("+300+300")
    your_gui.attributes("-topmost", True)
    your_gui.title('AutoClicker')  # Set title
    try:
        your_gui.iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
    except:
        pass
    your_gui.resizable(False, False)
    your_gui.configure(background="#e7dff2")
    your_gui.mainloop()
input(" ")
```

This is at the end of the source code

Comment: Wasn't this question already asked yesterday? Why repost?

Comment: Yeah cause I had to delete it.

Comment: Can you give us an exact error output?